# Javascript dependencies from Alfresco Activiti extensionElements

Tags: javascript, alfresco, activiti

I'd like to know if it is possible to better structure the Javascript code used within the task listeners of the Alfresco Activiti Listeners by referencing a dependency Javascript file or centrally defining Javascript methods that can be used by any node of the workflow.

Hopefully, it's possible but I just haven't seen where it is documented.

I would like to include or somehow make Javascript methods available which can be included as dependencies and called from within a ScriptTaskListener block.  I'm not talking about Javascript in forms, but the Javascript used in the workflow definition file.

I find myself repeating code across the different listener blocks in large workflows.  And I think that some of the code could potentially be reused in other workflow projects if I could include a reference to a dependency file.

For example, I have a requirement now to be able to capture and log some information upon completion of some of the userTasks of a workflow.  I'd like to avoid replicating very similar code used in the "complete" event of a taskListeners for a number of the userTasks.

Comment: you can probably import it as it is done over here  http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/using-task-properties-workflow-script-01242012-1347

Answer (score 0):

You can do probably 2 things within your bpmn20 xml workflow.
One is use [service-tasks](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnEmailTask), but that one doesn't always works within Alfresco.

I use the following:

```
<scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Send Email" scriptFormat="javascript">
          <extensionElements>
            <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>
                     var mail = actions.create("mail");
                     mail.parameters.to = "test@bla.com";
                     mail.parameters.subject = "I'm done! " + bpm_workflowDescription;
                     mail.parameters.from = "alfresco@alfresco.com";
                     mail.parameters.text = "Body! ";
                     mail.execute(bpm_package);
                </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
            </activiti:executionListener>
          </extensionElements>
          <script><![CDATA[]]></script>
        </scriptTask>
```